# How to resolve error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘GdkSurface {aka struct _GdkSurface}’?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, incomplete-type, gdk

Questions about `incomplete type` errors have already been asked here often, but all of the solutions provided there do not help in my case. Adding a forward declaration makes no sense, as `GdkSurface` has been forward declared already in the Gdk headers. Including the appropriate headers has already been done. Following the error producing code portion + includes.

```
#include <gdkmm/display.h>
#include <gdkmm/surface.h>

extern "C" {
#include <gdk/x11/gdkx.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
}

extern "C" {
    void surface_move(Gdk::Surface* psurface, int x, int y) {
        #ifdef GDK_WINDOWING_X11
        GdkSurface* surface = psurface->gobj();
        GdkSurface *impl = GDK_X11_SURFACE(surface);
        XMoveWindow(GDK_SURFACE_XDISPLAY (surface), GDK_SURFACE_XID (surface), x * impl->surface_scale, y * impl->surface_scale);
        #endif
    }
}
```

Here are the complete errors:

```
src/utils.cpp: In function ‘void Gdk::surface_move(Gdk::Surface*, int, int)’:
src/utils.cpp:9:83: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘GdkSurface {aka struct _GdkSurface}’
 (GDK_SURFACE_XDISPLAY (surface), GDK_SURFACE_XID (surface), x * impl->surface_scale, y * impl->surface_scale);
                                                                     ^~
In file included from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:29:0,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/enums.h:29,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/event.h:29,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/display.h:30,
                 from ./include/libgdp/utils.hpp:3,
                 from src/utils.cpp:1:
/home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:97:16: note: forward declaration of ‘GdkSurface {aka struct _GdkSurface}’
 typedef struct _GdkSurface             GdkSurface;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/utils.cpp:9:108: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘GdkSurface {aka struct _GdkSurface}’
 rface), GDK_SURFACE_XID (surface), x * impl->surface_scale, y * impl->surface_scale);
                                                                     ^~
In file included from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:29:0,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/enums.h:29,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/event.h:29,
                 from /home/user/.local/built/include/gtkmm-4.0/gdkmm/display.h:30,
                 from ./include/libgdp/utils.hpp:3,
                 from src/utils.cpp:1:
/home/user/.local/built/include/gtk-4.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:97:16: note: forward declaration of ‘GdkSurface {aka struct _GdkSurface}’
 typedef struct _GdkSurface             GdkSurface;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I built Gdk, Gtk, Gdkmm and Gtkmm with JHbuild.

Comment: *"but all of the solutions provided there do not help in my case"* -- this is largely uninformative. What is it about your case that makes it different? Don't just tell us that this is not a duplicate question; **demonstrate** that it is not.

Comment: Your example code is far from minimal. I would expect the function in a [mre] to consist of *one* line triggering the error, plus whatever definitions are required for that line. At that point, your error log should be short enough that you don't shy away from copying the error message *into the question itself*. Links go stale, so don't rely on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this type is private to GDK by design (only a forward declaration is provided). From the [GDK4 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/GdkSurface.html#GdkSurface-struct):

> The `GdkSurface` `struct` contains only private fields and should not
> be accessed directly.

See [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gdk/gdksurfaceprivate.h) for the header in which it is defined (which is not distributed). This is why you get these errors, all you have is a forward declaration to pass around pointers and references. All access to data members is forbidden.

To solve this, you have to use functions that work on surfaces (that are public), such as [`gdk_surface_get_scale_factor`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/GdkSurface.html#gdk-surface-get-scale-factor) or something similar instead of trying to access data members directly.